# How do I get a standalone (no install necessary) JDK 8 for Java coding on Mac?

Tags: java, ide

I am using a public computer and I want to do some Java coding on it*. I was able to download IntelliJ and I was able to copy it to my desktop and run it (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7a8D.jpg)), but I was not able to install the JDK due to lack of administrator privileges (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiqAa.jpg)).

How do I get a standalone (no install necessary) JDK 8 to use with IntelliJ on Mac?

*Note: The exact reason is I do not have a working computer and I have a coding interview (with Triplebyte, see [here](https://triplebyte.com/static/interview_guide_2h_v2)) that involves finding and fixing bugs in a Maven Project.

Answer (score 1):

Download a Zulu build. They come as a zip file for MacOS.

https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-mac/